# How to consume ServiceStack's ServerEventsClient OnMessage asynchronously

Tags: c#, servicestack, server-sent-events

I'm looking for a way for this part of the code to be asynchronous.

```
var sse = new ServerEventsClient(apiUrl)
{
  OnMessage = HandleResponse
};
```

I've looked at "Using C# Async/Await friendly API’s" here https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client#using-c-asyncawait-friendly-apis and I'm not sure if the code provided only works for one future message or every message that will come. I'll be sending a lot of requests in which I expect server responses via SSE so I'd like every response to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnMessage` is a synchronous event which fires as soon as it receives a message, it doesn't have an async alternative callback.

If you want to handle the messages asynchronously you can decouple the producer from its consumers which can do using a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) where you can the SSE Client capturing messages as soon as they're sent, e.g:

```
using var bc = new BlockingCollection<ServerEventMessage>();
using var sse = new ServerEventsClient(apiUrl) {
  OnMessage = bc.Add
};
await sse.Connect();
//...
```

Then you can have multiple sync & async consumers handling messages at their own pace independent of how fast they're being received with `Take`, `TryTake` or `GetConsumingEnumerable` APIs, e.g:

```
await Task.Run(async () => {
    foreach (var msg in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // handle msg
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
});
```

When you want to stop handling messages (e.g. when disposing ServerEventsClient) you can notify and short-circuit consumers with:

```
bc.CompleteAdding();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and also an example of a solution.
Also, can you please answer about the second part of the question concerning client.WaitForNextMessage()? Does it only work for the first message that will come?

Comment: @MladenRistic You can call `client.WaitForNextMessage()` again to return a task for fetching the next message.